# telling multiple events apart with NSURLConnection and asynchronous connections

Tags: ios, http, networking, network-programming

I'm writing an iPad app that populates a UI based on some JSON data grabbed from a server. I'm using NSURLConnection to make the initial connection thusly:

```
// Create the request.
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com/login"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString* credentials = @"username=testFoo&password=passFoo";

self.fFooConnectionData = [credentials dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:self.fFooConnectionData];

self.fFooDataConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[self.fFooDataConnection start];
```

Now, my issue is that I can catch the response in the 'connectionDidX' delegate functions, but for subsequent steps, how should I proceed? If this was a synchronous connection, the matter would be easier, I'd just wait for the return value, but with an asynchronous connection, how would I handle subsequent requests? How do I tell one event (like logging in) from another (like requesting specific data for the UI)?

Answer (score 0):

Each asynchronous method, function or asynchronous operation has a means to "signal" the client that it has finished.

`NSURLConnection` uses *delegate methods* to signal "events" to the delegate. The delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading:` respectively `connection:didFailWithError:` signal that the data is finally downloaded, respectively that an error has occurred.

The "call site" (that is the delegate instance in case of `NSURLConnection`) should now define *what* to do next *within* the delegate method.

You just need to ensure that the "execution context" for the *next* action is appropriate: for example, in a certain setup of `NSURConnection`, the delegate methods may be invoked on a private secondary thread. Suppose, the client want's to use the downloaded data and display it in a table view. UIKit methods shall be invoked only on the main thread. Thus, one need to ensure that through, for example, dispatching the actions onto the appropriate queue, the main queue.

Handling more complex `NSURLConnection` tasks asynchronously, the delegate approach to signal asynchronous events becomes quickly unwieldy. The better approach is to use asynchronous operations for network tasks. You can "wrap" your `NSURLConnection` task into a subclass of `NSOperation` for that dedicated purpose. What you get is a probably sophisticated class that handles all the complexity internally and provided an easy to use API. The client needs to specify a "completion handler" (a block) instead of handling delegate methods. This greatly reduces dependencies between objects and tremendously simplifies your coding task.

Then, it's basically the same as already said above:

The "call site" (that is the client of the `NSOperation` network subclass) should now define *what* to do next *within* the completion handler.

Well, even a `NSOperation` subclass may become unwieldy, especially if you have to setup the many parameters for the request and do all the nasty and elaborate error handling. What you might want occasionally is an even simpler way to invoke it. So, you may define a *very particular* "method" say,

`-(void) fetchMessagesWithUser:(User*)user completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;`

Internally, you implement the method based on your subclass of `NSOperation` which is itself implemented on top of `NSURLConnection`. You put all the nasty boiler plate stuff into it, including extensively error checks.

Then, your code becomes much more "clean":

```
- (void) fetchUserMessages 
{
   [self fetchMessagesWithUser:self.currentUser completion:^(id result){
        // result is an NSData containing JSON (array of messages for a user) or an NSError
        if (![result isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
             NSArray* messages = ...  // invoke JSON parser
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self updateViewWithMessages:messages];
             });
        }
        else {
            [self handleError:result];
        }
   }];
}
```